# Tracking change from last valid response in a for loop

Tags: r

I would like to track the number of changes in successive judgements over several repeated measurement. This is easy enough when all responses are complete

```
vec1 <- c("plus", "plus", "minus", "plus")

for (i in 2:4) {
  vec1[i+3] <- ifelse(vec1[i] == vec1[i-1], "no change", "change")
}

vec1

[1] "plus"      "plus"      "minus"     "plus"      "no change" "change"    "change"
```

The three new entries at the end of `vec1` track the change, from one entry to the next, over the first four entries.

However when there are missing entries the system breaks down

```
vec2 <- c("plus", "minus", NA, "plus")

for (i in 2:4) {
  vec2[i+3] <- ifelse(vec2[i] == vec2[i-1], "no change", "change")
}

vec2

[1] "plus"   "minus"  NA       "plus"   "change" NA       NA
```

I would like the machine to track the change not from the immediately preceding entry (whatever it is), but from the immediately preceding **valid** entry.

So I would like the output for `vec2` to be

```
[1] "plus"   "minus"  NA       "plus"   "change" NA       "change
```

with the final entry reflecting the fact that the fourth entry (`"plus"`) was different from the last valid entry, entry two (`"minus"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a convenient function `na.locf` in `zoo` which fills in an NA with the most recent non-NA value.

```
vec1 <- c("plus", "plus", "minus", "plus")
vec2 <- c("plus", "minus", NA, "plus")

lag_change <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x[-1] == zoo::na.locf(head(x, -1)), "no change", "change")
}

lag_change(vec1)
lag_change(vec2)
```

Comment: Thank you @Eugene for the answer. However unfortunately when I ran your code on the original vec2 `vec2 <- c("plus", "minus", NA, "plus")`, it returned `[1] "change" NA       "change" "change"` (a vector of four elements not three) and an error message `Warning message: In vec2[-1] == zoo::na.locf(lag(vec2)) : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: Not sure how that's possible. maybe copy/paste the code you ran here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Eugene. Just ran 

`rm(list=ls())


vec1 <- c("plus", "plus", "minus", "plus")
vec2 <- c("plus", "minus", NA, "plus")

lag_change <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x[-1] == zoo::na.locf(lag(x)), "no change", "change")
}

lag_change(vec1)
lag_change(vec2)`

And got ouput:

`[1] "no change" "change"    "change"    "no change"` and `[1] "change" NA       "change" "change"` respectively, each with the error message I reproduced in my previous comment. It's still workable though, if I remove the fourth element in the returned vector

Comment: my bad! i think lag was masked for me. I've updated the answer